# Linked template template parameters - constraining the inner parameter to be the same

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have some code that makes heavy use of template classes.  It's possible but not desirable at this point to change the existing code base.  I need to write a new class that will act on two template classes that (for the purposes of this question) are arbitrary except for having a common template argument.  A simplified example:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
    // Implementation details
};

template<typename T>
class B {
    // Implementation details
};

template<typename T, typename X<T>, typename Y<T>> // This syntax is invalid!
class C {
    // Implementation details
};
```

I need to write class `C`.  The syntax shown in the example is suggestive of what I want to do but does not work.  The template parameters `X` and `Y` here must be "tied together" by taking the same template argument `T`.  Other than that, they can be arbitrary.

This means that something "like" `C<std::string,A<std::string>,B<std::string>>` should be valid but `C<std::string,A<std::string>,B<std::map>>` should not because `A` and `B` do not have the same template argument. (The "like" in quotes again denotes that the syntax is still wrong in the declaration of `C` above.)

Other attempts (which also failed) included:

- `template<typename T, template<typename> class X<T>, template<typename> class Y<T>>`
- `template<typename T> template<typename X<T>, typename Y<T>>`

Is anything like this possible?  If so, what is the syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `template<typename T, template<typename> class X, template<typename> class Y>` and then `X<T>` and `Y<T>` wherever you need in your `C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could partially-specialize `C`:

```
//Primary template
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y>
class C;

//Specialization for when the template parameters are the same
template<typename T, template <typename> class X, template <typename> class Y>
class C <T, X<T>, Y<T>> {
    // Implementation details
};
```

If you then use invalid template arguments, you'll get a compile-time error.

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2fcb48bf75062be)

Comment: This answer did what I wanted. With some more tinkering, I was able to improve it a bit further so that the parameter `T` does not need to be supplied explicitly by the user.  The primary template is `template<typename X, typename Y> class C` and the specialization is `template<template <typename> class X, template <typename> class Y, typename T> class C<X<T>, Y<T>>`.

Comment: @Brick How's that different from the answer?

Comment: @einpoklum The primary template has one less parameter, which then trickles down to slightly simpler code throughout.

Comment: Following the suggestion by @einpoklum, I made my comment on this answer an answer of its own. That provides a slight improvement over the original by TartanLlama.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment to the accepted answer by TartanLlama, I was able to improve this slightly such that there is one less template parameter involved.  This leads to slightly simpler code.

The primary template becomes

```
template<typename X, typename Y> class C
```

and the specialization is

```
template<template<typename> class X, template<typename> class Y, typename T> class C<X<T>, Y<T>>
```

The difference here is that the primary template does not have the additional template parameter `T` relative to what was first suggested by TartanLlama.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely an improvement :)